# Why I can't keep the hash updated in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, user-input, updating

I need to update this hash with as many items as the user wants. And I have a problem with updating it. 
It only shows the last input from user.

For example in i = 2, the hash will only show the second key and value added, and I want both. Or if i = 3 i need all three inputs.

```
puts "how may items to add in hash?" 

i=gets.chomp.to_i
for i in 1..i
            puts "add key"
             key = gets.chomp                   
            puts "add value"
             value = gets.chomp.to_f.round(2)

            project = Hash.new()
            project = {key => value}

            project.each do |key, value|
            puts "#{key} \t - \t #{value}%"
            end
end
```

Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your variable initialization our of the loop. Right now you rewrite your project with blank hash on each iteration. That's why it stores only the last item. Here is your possible code:

```
puts "how may items to add in hash?"

project = {}
i=gets.chomp.to_i

for i in 1..i
  puts "add key"
  key = gets.chomp                   
  puts "add value"
  value = gets.chomp.to_f.round(2)

  project[key] = value
end

project.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} \t - \t #{value}%"
end

project.values.inject(&:+)
```

PS: Prefer `{}` over `Hash.new()` (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#literal-array-hash)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Why?

Comment: @AlinChiver Maybe you need to move `project.each` if you want to get listing only once rather then get it on every iteration

Comment: You are setting a new value for variable `project` in every iteration.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Lol, thanks. You are right. Pretty hard to debug without real output

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea how can I sum all the values the user has inputed? I know I'm stepping over the line now, but I need to finish this project as soon as possible...